# Puzzle: ActiveRecord object is persisted but cannot be retrieved with find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, factory-bot

I am experiencing a head-scratcher in a non-Rails app using AR that I cannot figure out.  I will simplify greatly, but here is the essence: I have a Download object that belongs to a Ledger.  In one of my unit tests, I am experiencing this:

```rb
dl = create(:download, account: checking)
dl.ledger
 => <Byr::Ledger:0x00007fd176ce4740

 id: 2,
 name: "test_ledger_1",
 org_name: "Test Ledger, Inc.",
 street1: nil,
 street2: nil,
 city: nil,
 state: nil,
 zip: nil,
 created_at: 2022-04-03 13:13:53.734003153 UTC,
 updated_at: 2022-04-03 13:13:53.792451592 UTC,
 default_account_id: 21,
 short_name: "Test_ledger_1",
 parent_percent: nil,
 parent_id: nil,
 accessed_at: 2022-04-03 13:13:53.791911547 UTC,
 start_date: Mon, 01 Jan 2018,
 cost_method: "fifo",
 end_date: nil
> dl.ledger.peristed? => true
> Ledger.find(2) => nil with eval error: Couldn't find Byr::Ledger with 'id'=2
```

I use factory_bot to create the Download, dl, which in turn builds a ledger for it to go with, which purports to be persisted with id=2.  But when I try to find the ledger with Ledger.find(2), it's not in the postgresql db.

Anybody have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: try to log `dl.ledger.id` and `Ledger.find(dl.ledger.id)` and see what you get

Comment: @Joe: dl.ledger.id   => 2; Ledger.find(dl.ledger.id) => Couldn't find Byr::Ledger with 'id'=2

Comment: Didn't expect that. What does querying for `Ledger.all` and `Byr::Ledger.all` returns?

Comment: @Joe, thanks for giving this some thought: `Ledger.all => []`, even though, as you see, the dl.ledger has an id of 2.  I've also brought up a pgsql console and confirmed that the `ledgers` table is empty.  I also get `dl.ledger.valid? => true`.

Comment: Ok, then you should have `Ledger.exists?(dl.ledger.id) => false`. Don't always trust `peristed?` as this method doesn't query the db

Comment: @Joe: sure enough, `Ledger.exists(dl.ledger.id) => false`, so it doesn't seem to get created.  How would it acquire an `id` without actually getting put in the db?

Comment: @Joe:  I should mention that I am using `DatabaseCleaner` with the `:transaction` method, but this all occurs within a single example, so I can't see how it would be involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like [faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker) + [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) and mock resources to get access to params you need.
[Here](https://medium.com/@JPLynch35/crank-out-tests-with-factory-bot-and-faker-e83a31a7693c) an example of use. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to pass by explicitly passing the ledger into the Account factory on which the Download factory was created, like this:

```
let(:ldg) { create(:ledger, name: 'Willy') }
let(:checking) { create(:bank_account, ledger: ldg) }
let(:dl) { create(:download, account: checking) }
```

Suddenly, the disappearing ledgers abated.  I believe the cuplrit may have been DatabaseCleaner wiping away the automatically-generated ledger from one example to the next.  Using an explicit ledger just for the example in question kept it from being deleted underneath my feet.

Thanks, @Joe, for giving this some thought.